# Failed to resolve: com.xwray:groupie:2.9.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, groupie

I want to add groupie dependency but it gives me the following error after syncing.

[image]

And when I try to run my program it gives me this error.
[image]

these are my dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
// groupie for managing complex recycler view adapter
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
```

Comment: have you declared `jcenter()` the latest version was released there

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu sorry I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside build gradle[project]
Make sure you add `jcenter()`

```
buildscript {
      repositories{
            jcenter()
       }
}
```

```
allprojects {
      repositories{
            jcenter()
       }
}
```

If it's added you can try out earlier version

Comment: thanks bro. I updated android studio to 4.2 and after loading my older project it was telling me that jcenter() depricated and I removed it.

Comment: after adding jcenter() now it is working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that @Meraj :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you used the solution provided by @Ananiya above and added the dependencies to project build, and are still getting error, remove the

```
allprojects {
  repositories{
        jcenter()
   }
}
```

block from project level gradle and add the `jcenter()` dependency inside the `repositories` block in `settings.gradle`, this is because `RepositoryHandler` is preferably managed by `settings.gradle`